# Running GTM diagnose error

Tags: android, eclipse, lint

When I try to clean my android projects in Eclipse, I always get this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Running GTM diagnose".
com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.XmlContext: method <init>(Lcom/android/tools/lint/client/api/LintDriver;Lcom/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Project;Lcom/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Project;Ljava/io/File;Lcom/android/resources/ResourceFolderType;)V not found
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: am also getting the same error while saving the xml files in values folder

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Did you possibly update your SDK & ADT? I think that may be what is causing this

Comment: I am also having the same problem while saving strings.xml file

Comment: I've also have save problem in saving string.xml files.

Answer (score 2):

I just uninstalled the ATM (**Android Translation Manager**), and the error disappears.

In Eclipse *go to -> Help -> Installation Details -> Select the ATM and click in Uninstall*.

**Restart** eclipse and **DONE**.

At least for me the error message is *gone*.

Comment: I don't see "Installation Details". Did you mean something else?

Comment: Maybe is the Eclipse Version, im using LUNA: http://imgur.com/0qtc9Aw.
Try this: Help -> About -> Installation Details -> Select the ATM and click in Uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've solved the problem. After updating to `ADT v23` I've installed `Android Translation Manager` too which I never used before. I've moved my `strings.xml` file to `values-en` folder and I never got that message again. Separating languages from `values` folder solved the problem but I think maybe it should caused by Android Translation Manager, maybe a bug but I should run more tests... .

Comment: did this cause any bugs? like say if the phone was not in english would it throw an error? Also, do you need to keep a strings.xml in the values folder?

Comment: @Sree No, you don't need to keep `strings.xml` in values folder. I'm still searching for this question and it's not a serious error but annoying one.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your string file triggers "Missing Translation" error in Android Lint. This error means that there are strings in your string file that are not translated to other languages. To stop the pop up error windows, right click your android project -> property -> Android Lint Preferences -> Change the severity of "Missing Translation" to error.

Comment: Disabling all the lint error checkings doesn't remove the GTM Diagnose Error. Thanks anyway,

Comment: It reappeared for me as well. Sorry for producing a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I started getting allot of Errors being thrown at me and I finally found something that appears to have worked and actually makes allot of sense considering the problems. This has worked for me so I hope you get the same success. When I updated to the newest android my settings for eclipse had some legacy issues. I deleted the .settings file for eclipse and then fixed the set up an no more problems.

**WARNING DELETING THE SETTINGS FILE WILL BREAK THINGS UNTIL YOU RECONFIGURE THEM I SHOW THE STEPS YOU SHOULD NEED TO FOLLOW**

1. Go to (assuming windows) *C:\ProgramFiles\Eclipse\configuration\* and delete *.settings*. For other machines go to the elipse install directory shoud work just the same
2. Relauch eclipse. (Everything will be broken that's okay) If not broken still do the same steps.
3. Open from the menu bar 

   *Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler*
4. Make sure that *Enable project specific settings* is NOT checked
5. Go to the project explorer and Right click on the Project Root and go to:

   *Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties*  (this will fix and legacy errors that might still have carried over)
6. If you have multiple versions of Java install continue on otherwise you should be done
7. Open from Menu Bar 

   *Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs* Make sure it is set to the most recent
8. Open from Menu Bar 

   *Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler* Use default settings

After that just build a clean version and it should be running just fine. Hope this works for you.

Comment: So I still have errors in the Strings.xml but nowhere else